# Почему SQLite3 не обновляет данные в таблице?

Tags: python, sqlite

У меня есть такой код:

```
def SetDialog(chat_id):

c.execute('UPDATE managers SET status == ? WHERE id == ?', (1, chat_id,))
user = c.execute('SELECT * FROM queue').fetchmany(1)
c.execute("INSERT INTO chats VALUES(?, ?)", (user[0][1], chat_id))
chat = int(user[0][1])
c.execute("DELETE FROM queue WHERE chat_id = ?", (chat,))
conn.commit()
return chat
```

Он работает абсолютно корректно, за исключением запроса на обновление данных. Данные просто не обновляются, никаких ошибок, он просто спокойно пробегает жту строку и всё. Я как только не пытался это починить, и выносил обьект conn за пределы функции и помещал его в разные кавички, - ничего не помогает.
Как это чинить?

Comment: сделать курсор С глобальной переменной

Comment: не помогло, старнно что в других проектах все работает

Comment: `status == ?` - заменить `==` на `=`